# Should I use mount or autofs?

Tags: centos, mount, fstab, autofs

I have NFS shares on a file server that I would like to mount on a web server.

For example, a music streamer web application (subsonic) would be hosted on the web server and stream music files located on the file server via NFS shares.

1) Would it be better if I used autofs rather than a simple mount in fstab?

2) Could I use the same system to store web pages without losing performance? (Web pages rendered on the web server but ruby or php files stored on the NFS share). That way, a small team of devs could work on a shared folder and view the result on the webserver.

Comment: Better for who?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to define what you mean by 'better'.
- The performance question should be easy to test in lab. Setup each scenario and run your workload on them both. Measure ad make decisions based on what you learn.